# how to XPath a little more structure into a HTML document

Tags: html, xpath

How, using XPath can I parse this HTML and end up able to access a list of H2 titles "Foo bar", "Bar baz" and access to lists of paragraph content "associated" with each H2?

```
<!-- lots of html -->
<h2>Foo bar</h2>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>ipsum</p>
<p>etc</p>

<h2>Bar baz</h2>
<p>dum dum dum</p>
<p>poopfiddles</p>
<!-- lots more html ... -->
```

The closest query I have only pulls out the paragraph content from which I'd be unable to work out which h2 tag it belonged to:

```
//h2/following-sibling::p
```

My HTML is a special case and every H2 is followed by the same number of p tags.
Thus is clunky OR solution returns the elements I need.

```
//h2 | //h2/following-sibling::p
```

I'm not providing this as *the* answer as I'm sure there is a more elegant and generalised solution.

Comment: I don't see a question here, I see a piece of HTML and you saying something you'd like. Have you tried anything ? did you get an error ? do you actually have a question for us ?

Comment: I've edited my question. The closest I got to getting results was using this query: "//following-sibling::h2" but as many will know, it'll not return paragraph content.

Answer (score 1):

The following Xpath will find any `h2` which is followed by a `<p>`.

```
//h2[following-sibling::p]
```

If you can be more specific about the criteria (e.g. must have exactly 3 `<p>` siblings and no `<table>`'s etc, then we can be more specific. Also, the use of `//` is unfortunate - this should be tightened up to match the flow of your `xhtml` document.

Comment: that's great Stuart. I tried this and it does indeed return me the h2 tags/contents. As I mentioned I also want the content of those p tags in a structure I can know which h2 they belong too. Is this possible with XPath?